# Is my producer/consumer solution correct?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, producer-consumer

I'm trying to learn more about threads and thought that coming up with a solution to the producer/consumer problem would be a good start. One of the constraints I put on the solution was that the consumer does not know ahead of time how much the producer is producing. The code runs as expected and I've run it many many times, but that doesn't mean that it is free of flaws.  Are there any problems with this solution?

```
package Multithreading.ProducerConsumer;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class ProducerConsumer
{
    private class Producer implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                try 
                {
                    canProduce.acquire();
                    mutex.acquire();
                    queue.add(i);
                    mutex.release();
                    canConsume.release();
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException ex) 
                {
                    ;
                }
            }
            try
            {
                canConsume.acquire();
                isTryingToFinish = true;
                canConsume.release();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                ;
            }
        }
    }

    private class Consumer implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while(!isDone)
            {
                try
                {
                    canConsume.acquire();
                    mutex.acquire();
                    System.out.println(queue.pop());
                    if(isTryingToFinish && queue.isEmpty())
                    {
                        isDone = true;
                    }
                    mutex.release();
                    canProduce.release();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    ;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Semaphore canProduce;
    Semaphore canConsume;
    Semaphore mutex;
    boolean isTryingToFinish = false;
    boolean isDone = false;
    final static int bufferSize = 100;
    LinkedList<Integer> queue;

    public ProducerConsumer()
    {
        queue = new LinkedList<>();
        canProduce = new Semaphore(bufferSize);
        canConsume = new Semaphore(0);
        mutex = new Semaphore(1);
    }

    public void Go() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread p = new Thread(new Producer());
        Thread c = new Thread(new Consumer());
        p.start();
        c.start();
        p.join();
        c.join();
        System.out.println("Job Complete!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        ProducerConsumer p = new ProducerConsumer();
        p.Go();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should acquire mutexes/locks/etc before a `try` block and release them (in reverse order!!) in the `finally` block!!

Comment: Also, your `boolean`s should be at the very least volatile

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [MSDN's 'Example 2: Synchronizing two threads: a producer and a consumer'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vcwlkthreadingtutorialexample2synchronizing). It's c# but that should not be a problem.